# useUnicode property not available on com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hikaricp

I am doing an upgrade of our application from SpringBoot 1.5.9 to 2.1.3.

We are using MySQL datasource.

Before upgrading to Spring Boot 2, we used a property          config.addDataSourceProperty("useUnicode","true");.

Now with the new implementation, setting this property is not possible - the application won't start. 
So in Spring Boot 1, the used class was com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource, but now in Spring Boot 2, the class is com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource.
Anyone has any idea if this property should be set anymore?
Best Regards

Comment: you will have to force by using the property `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${database.url}?useUnicode=true`

Comment: So does this mean that it is not set by default?

Comment: Yes,so far I know it depends on database management system.